# Escrevi esse código no Dev C++, ele compilou mas não realiza a operação

Tags: c, c++, algoritmo

Quando executo e digito um número ele não faz a multiplicação, só exibe a mensagem " Preço:" e não o resultado da multiplicação.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()

{

int quantidade;
double valor;
scanf("%d", &quantidade);

        if(quantidade<12)
        {
          printf ("Preço:");
          valor=quantidade*1.3;

        }
        else
        {
         printf ("Preço:");
         valor=quantidade*1.0;

        }
```

Comment: Ele está fazendo exatamente o que você mandou fazer. Inclusive ele faz a multiplicação. Mas por alguma razão parece que não é o que deseja, por isso precisaria escrever na pergunta o que deveria ter acontecido na sua concepção.

Comment: Ele não exibe o resultado na execução, só aparece "Preço:".

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 4):

O maior problema é que não está mandando imprimir o resultado. Tudo o que quer que o código faça você tem que dizer. E não precisa dizer nada que seja desnecessário. Esse código poderia ser simplificado já que o objetivo dele parece ser apenas ler um número e dependendo dele gerar outro número baseado nele multiplicado por um fator predeterminado. Então só precisa ter uma variável para armazenar o dado pedido para digitar, pedir para digitar e mandar imprimir o cálculo, que pode ser feita em uma expressão condicional simples. Reforço, se não mandar imprimir o resultado ele não será impresso, nada acontece como mágica no código. E compilar é uma preocupação desnecessária, o que importa é o código estar certo, ter compilado não é medida de algo certo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int quantidade;
    scanf("%d", &quantidade);
    printf("Preço: %lf", quantidade * (quantidade < 12 ? 1.3 : 1.0));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qLBvvr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vrufbsga-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/PrintResult.c).

A pergunta fala em C++, mas esse código é C e não C++, mesmo que ele compile em C++, é bom ter em mente que não é C++. E eu não usaria este IDE, ele é bastante criticado.